# If cell contains this, this or this, then return TRUE, else false: Excel formula

Tags: macos, excel-formula

I have a column that has numbers 1-5 or nothing. I would like to return TRUE or 1 if the number in the cells of that column is 3, 4 or 5.

I am using Excel 2011 for Mac. I know this is super simple, but no amount of googling has helped.
Somebody please help.

Thanks!

Comment: This should help: http://www.brimagency.com/blog/unconditional-love-for-conditional-formulas/

Comment: `IF` + `OR` will get you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned already in the comments, a simple IF + OR formula will get you there (formula assumes column with numbers is column A):

```
=IF(OR(A1=3,A1=4,A1=5),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!
I followed Val's article and deduced the best way to go for this formula is:
    =IF(X3>2,1,0)
I got the same return with Dane's answer.

And that worked as intended, thanks again!